# Does injecting a generic interface with concrete types defeat the purpose of dependency injection?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, interface

Consider the following scenario.

```
public interface IRestaurant<IDinner, IDesert> { }

public class Pasta : IDinner {}
public class Cake : IDesert {}

public class Chef 
{
    // resolving a mix of interfaces and concrete classes
    public Chef(IRestaurant<Pasta, Cake>) { }
}
```

Does the injection of two concrete classes defeat the purpose of dependency injection? My sense is that it does, because we are now strongly coupled to the `Pasta` and `Cake` classes whereas dependency injection is there to break that coupling.

Would the following make more sense?

```
public class Chef<IDinner, IDesert>
{
    public Chef(IRestaurant<IDinner, IDesert>) { }
}
```

Comment: Can a chef make a meal that has dinners and deserts other than pasta and cake?

Comment: In the first example, no, in the second example, yes.

Comment: I guess it comes down to intent, if a chef can only deal with that combination then using the concrete types seem fine. If they can deal with more combinations than that then a generic would be more appropriate. Perhaps if you wrote it as `public class PastaAndCakeChef` the intent would be more obvious?

Comment: I dont think that injecting concretes in and of themselves is always a bad thing, but if you intent is to create something generic the second way is best

Comment: I see what you mean. So in this case, what is the point of the dependency injection? It is not breaking the coupling, so what is it doing? Hiding the constructor is my only thought.

Comment: You are using dependency injection to ensure that you are given a suitable restaurant, any which serves pasta and cake i guess? The point of dependency injection is really around managing lifecycle and implementation selection. Decoupling becomes easier to do if you can control the implementation selection outside of the object but it isn't the only point of DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing concepts here- DI doesn't inherently have anything to do whether you use interfaces or concrete classes per se. You could (for example) inject a concrete class that was one of several subclasses of Pasta (`Linguini`, `Ravioli`, etc)., and the benefits of DI (low coupling, discrete testability) still apply.

Most people use interfaces because that further lowers the coupling to the specific interface you need, without implying any implementation (for example, maybe it doesn't make sense to have `GlutenFreeElbowNoodles` inherit from `Pasta`) but that isn't really an IoC concern.

Comment: Sure. It could be argued that dependency injection even applies in purely functional languages, where there are not even classes. DI is simply the separation of the implementation choice from the contract (usage). Hopefully that results in incentives for building an implementation that is better designed for independent testing.

Comment: It seems that Dependency Injection without interfaces/inheritance allows us to change a dependency's constructor's arguments from outside the dependent class. With interfaces/inheritance, we can also change the dependency's implementation from outside the class. Is that right? (Apologies for deleting my previous comment).

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but the general DI pattern (at least in Java/C#) is that anything passed to a constructor is a *required* dependency, and anything set as a property (getter/setter in Java) is an optional dependency (could be set, but the class can do it's work without it). Again, not specific to DI- you can of course change the implementation you use via normal code, DI just gives you a standard, consistent way of doing it.

Comment: What I am asking is whether this statement is true: "Dependency injection is valuable in a language without inheritance and becomes more powerful in a language that has inheritance."

Comment: OK- you didn't ask about inheritance you asked about interfaces. Those are different things. I don't think that DI has a place in a language that doesn't have inheritance, unless you are talking about a purely functional language where you could inject any method with a given signature.

Comment: It seems like DI would have a place in languages that lack inheritance. Say `ClassA` has a `ClassB`. Without DI, `ClassA` fully controls the arguments that it passes to `ClassB`'s constructor. With DI, the container (or the unit test during testing) can control the arguments that pass to `ClassB`'s constructor. This seems like a real benefit, because we can control how `ClassB` gets instantiated from outside of `ClassA`.

Comment: But without inheritance or interfaces, how would class B specify (generically) that it could accept the real or test implementation?

Comment: True. Without inheritance, `ClassB` can accept only one implementation. It can, though, specify its willingness to accept a `ClassB` with test constructor arguments. It's the differences between receiving a `new ClassB(realDatabase)` and a `new ClassB(testDatabase)`.

Comment: I can't see any benefit to DI at all if there's no decoupling. It would be functionally identical to having a builder class for every class with dependencies and nesting them. It makes my head hurt.

Comment: Here are some benefits of DI without inheritance/polymorphism: 1. DI manages all the complexity of "a builder class for every class with dependencies..." 2. DI allows management of the inversion-of-control in one place. 3. DI avoids hard coding constant values into our code (much like storing the database connection string in an environmental variable instead of hard coding it into code).